# .htaccess mod_rewrite get param to language folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my curriculum on the address http://www.myname.com/cv/
In the /cv/ folder I have:
   **index.php**

```
if (!empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
} else {
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}
switch ($lang) {
    case "en":
        include("index-en.html");
        break;
    case "it":
        include("index-it.html");
        break;
    default:
        include("index-en.html");
        break;
}
```

so the **index-en.html** or **index-it.html** page is included based on the browser language or a switch on either pages with the `$_GET[]` parameter like http://www.myname.com/cv/?lang=it

All good but now I would like pretty URL's like http://www.myname.com/cv/it/

I am a newbie with mod_rewrite.. This is what I tried in the .htaccess file in the root of my **public_html** folder, under the WP-block

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
# in case someone accesses with capitals
RewriteRule ^CV/(.*)$ http://www.myname.com/cv/ [R=301,L]
# pretty URL's for the language
RewriteRule ^cv/(en|it|)/(.*)$ cv/index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: OK I got this working `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(en|it|)[/]?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]` but only with a seperate .htaccess file in the /cv/ folder..

Comment: Your first rules were okay (delete the second `|`, though), you just needed them *before* WordPress's rules.